# how to show success message in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

how to show success message in laravel  5.1, and where to call,this one is   added my blade page

```
<div class="alert-success" id="popup_notification">
 <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong>    {{ Session::get('success') }}
</div>
```

Comment: You could do that adding to main layout file or put it under separate notification.blade.php file and include it on your blade files

Comment: You could also try using this package https://github.com/laracasts/flash

Comment: Hi Sir actually I have used {!! Html::script('js/modernizr.custom.80028.js') !!} this plugin it is working fine, but two time displayed what is the reason sir please tell me

Comment: alert.blade.php :

Comment: <div class="alert-success" id="popup_notification">
 <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong>    {{ Session::get('success') }}
</div>

Comment: and my controller page: I called

Comment: return Redirect::route($this->cdroute, array($customer_id))->with($this->success );

Comment: ->with($this->success );

Comment: Check out the answer written. That should work.

Comment: I will check it Sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133310/discussion-between-saravanan-sampathkumar-and-sivakumar-s).

Comment: Thank you sir It is working fine

Comment: Sir one more doubt

Comment: when I insert a record after displayed msg then display another time displayed popup msg ?what is the reason

Comment: You should use session flash message instead of normal session message

Answer (score 2):

Put this code into the main layout which you extend in the most of templates:

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert-success" id="popup_notification">
        <strong>{!! trans('main.message') !!}</strong>{{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

When you want to display a message, [flash it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data) in the controller:

```
return redirect('some-url')->with('success', 'It works!');
```

Or:

```
session()->flash('success', 'It works!');
return view('some.view');
```

Comment: Sir one more doubt

Comment: when I insert a record after displayed msg then display another time displayed popup msg ?what is the reason

Comment: Do you mean when you load next page, the message is still there? If yes, please show how do you flash the message.

Comment: first time displayed bottom of the navbar

Comment: second time displayed at the top popup window

Comment: any one please help me